# PhoneGap iframe issue

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm trying to develop an app with a few iframes on certain pages.

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>in.gr</title>
    </head>
    <script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
    <body style="margin:0;">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <iframe src="http://www.in.gr" border="0" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" / >
    </body>
</html>
```

and I've added inside the config.xml this:

```
<access origin="http://www.in.gr" />
```

My issue is that while in the phonegap application on my mobile, the iframe is shown perfectly, it turns blank when I'm uploading my zip to https://build.phonegap.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it, so anyone interested this is it!

```
<content src="http://somesite.com" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />

<allow-navigation href="http://somesite.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<access origin="*.www.in.gr"></access><allow-navigation href="*.www.in.gr"></allow-navigation>
```